# installing scipy package in windows

Tags: python

I want to install scipy packages and I know it's a repetitive question, but I have tried all of them but I didn't find a proper solution.
when write this :  import scipy
it executes successfully. but when I try this:

```
import scipy.spatial
```

I receive this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  

File "C:/Users/Hamid/Documents/kodeyaro/kodefolani.py", line 41, in <module>  

from scipy.spatial import Delaunay  

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 92, in module>  

 from .qhull import *  

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

what should I do?

Comment: switch to anaconda python. https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: thanks for your attention.

Comment: I found another solution. on Linux platform I used this command: sudo apt-get install scipy.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in the cmd:

`pip install scipy`

It is advisable to run cmd as Adminstrator.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I tried it Command Promt and I got this message:" 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external commnad, operable program or batch file.". what should I do?

Comment: I think you should add python Scripts folder to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 8):

below re-installation will fix the issue as required dll will be placed at right place.
user should have admin permissions on the system.

```
python -m pip install scipy --upgrade --force
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem when I switched to python38. Build was failing while scipy installation.

I solved by using prebuilt  libs from Prof: Gohlke

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Install appropriate numpy+mkl version using --force argument

```
pip install numpy-1.17.3+mkl-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl --force
```