# "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when trying to import gensim

Tags: numpy, scipy, gensim

While trying to import gensim, I run into the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\usr\Documents\hello\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gensim
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\gensim\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\gensim\corpora\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .indexedcorpus import IndexedCorpus  # noqa:F401 must appear before the other classes
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\gensim\corpora\indexedcorpus.py", line 15, in <module>
    from gensim import interfaces, utils
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\gensim\interfaces.py", line 21, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 21, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import entropy
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .qhull import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried uninstalling numpy, scipy and gensim using `pip` in the command prompt and installing them again, but this does not resolve the issue.

I have also looked at the suggestions to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253458/installing-scipy-package-in-windows), and tried installing [numpy‑1.19.0+mkl‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), but it resulted in a separate error `Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.` Thus, I have stuck to using numpy, scipy and gensim installed via `pip`.

Additionally, I installed scipy version 1.4.1 as the latest 1.5.0 version will give the following error as described in this link:
[Error when loading scipy: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62566691/error-when-loading-scipy-oserror-winerror-126-the-specified-module-could-not)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

For additional information, I am using Python 3.7 and Windows 10.

Comment: How are you installing (& uninstalling) these packages? Also, it looks like they're being installed into the system's Python environment (`site-packages`), but it's usually better practice to use a working or project-specific 'virtual environment', via either `venv` tool of Python or the `conda` system. (That's what the popular `anaconda` uses, though I prefer starting from a `miniconda` install, to have explicit control over everything installed.) Finally, if you have a choice – such as for a personal project – the whole Python scientific/ML stack tends to work smoothest on non-Windows OSes.

Comment: @gojomo thanks for your reply, I simply used pip to install/uninstall. E.g. `pip uninstall numpy` in command prompt and `pip install numpy`. I have tried using [numpy‑1.19.0+mkl‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) but that results in a numpy error saying that `Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.` I have `anaconda` installed, but I wanted to use VSCode for this project. `import gensim` works when I run .ipynb files, but not for .py files, which I would like to use.

Comment: I would suggest using the `conda` tool to (1) create new, explicit, named environment; (2) install the required packages into that environment. The conda repos often handle Windows-related native/compiled dependencies best, and working in a new environment would isolate any new experiments from any left over side-effects of failed attempts in the global `site-packages` environment. And to extent you make progress but hit new errors, quoting the full steps & error (with traceback) in your question can make it easier to know what the *current* state is, as opposed to fragmentary messages here.

Comment: @gojomo I wish I knew the importance of venvs earlier, but now all my packages from various projects are installed in `site-packages`. Is it recommended to delete everything there and create a virtual environment?

Comment: If you're sure you're only deleting those you installed, you could do that. But if `site-packages` isn't creating any errors for system-level, non-virtual-environment tools that also use Python, you can probably just ignore it, and use one or more venvs for other projects (which will ignore the `site-packages`). I tend to have one large 'scratch' environment I use for lots of things, but then start a fresh one when I need to be sure I'm using some latest/exact configuration, with specific versions, that should be reproducible elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried various things, but the only thing that worked for me was to install an older version of Gensim.

```
pip install gensim==3.7.0
```