# Scipy ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When I try to get scipy running, the following occurs:

```
>>> import scipy   
>>> from scipy import stats  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>  
    from scipy import stats  
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages  \Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>  
    from .stats import *  
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in <module>  
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist  
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>  
    from .qhull import *  
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I have googled the whole day now, but could not figure out a way to solve this problem. I found this question
["ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found" when trying to import gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636828/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-when-try)

and this sums up my whole problem, because I tried the exact same thing:

First, I used pip to install scipy and tried to uninstall and reinstall it.
Then, I also tried scipy version 1.4.1. with the success of being able to import scipy but not scipy.stats
Lastly, I also tried to uninstall numpy+mkl and then reinstall it again, which resulted in: 'Importing the numpy c-extensions failed'
I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Please, edit and use `/`/`/`` to display the error.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy and scipy rely on lower level fortran libraries such as BLAS and lapack to perform many of their functions. These libraries come in many different versions, including the highly portable ones available from netlib, and other which are optimised for particular systems. In particular, Intel has one called "MKL" - Intel Math Kernel Library. So numpy-mkl just means a version of numpy compiled against the MKL fortran library.

Probably whichever version of numpy you previously had installed was somehow broken, and couldn't find the libraries it needed.