# Importing Python Libraries

Tags: python

I am using python39 and have imported the libraries 'numpy, scipy, matplotlib, scikit-learn and sklearn.
I am then trying to use a command with sklearn library and it is not working with the below error

```
from sklearn import neighbors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import neighbors
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .base import clone
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing qhull: The specified module could not be found."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing scipy package in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253458/installing-scipy-package-in-windows)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to research your problem before posting here.  Show what happened when you tried to apply the solutions already available on line.

Comment: I have done some research on this problem and implemented all proposed solutions before posting here. I am using python for data science and this issue has been the reason I discovered this forum. I will be happy if someone has had something like this before and solved it.

Comment: @Prune, I finally solved my problem though u closed it. What you proposed didn't help. I went to another forum and researched and after taking time to read through, some proposition did help. Since I am using windows and intel, I had to add some dependencies: mkl, mkl-fft, intel-openmp and VC 2017 Redist. Once I did it, it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Since the duplicate didn't work, I reopened the question.
Please update it to Stack Overflow guidelines, and we'll be happy to archive it for future use.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below commands

C:\Python39\Scripts>pip install mkl_fft-1.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl force

C:\Python39\Scripts>pip install mkl_random-1.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl force

C:\Python39\Scripts>pip install mkl_random-1.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl force

Then I went back to my python shell and typed

> > > from sklearn import neighbors

*It worked*